# Can't unlock pattern on a MediaPad 7Lite!

Tags: locked-out

My son has a MediaPad 7lite and he has forgotten the pattern to unlock his device. The device is linked to his Google account.  When we tried to ask for help via the Google account, we discovered that his password works on other devices but not on his MediaPad? Is there any other way to recover the pattern that he created? Can anyone help us out please?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. May I suggest you start with [its tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info) where we already collected some details on the issue? If that doesn't bring the solution, please continue to check with other questions using that tag (simply click it). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.google.com/android/find and Lock the device. You will be able to set a new password for the phone and now use this new password to unlock your device. Make sure you are connected to the internet on your device or else this won't work.